# java - How can I look at the fourth element in a string if the strings are in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, string, arraylist, substring

I have this array list:

```
[Staff 77778 Julie Chang Registrar, Adjunct 19778 Mike Thompson CS mtxxx@gmail.com GITC2400, Staff 30041 Anne Mathews Security, Junior 98444 Serene Murray Math smyyy@gmail.com]
```

For each string in the array list, the fourth element is the last name. 
I have to search through the entire array list (which is actually 17 elements but I shortened the list to 4 elements for the purpose of asking this question) and whenever I see the last name the user is searching for, I have to return the entire string that contains that last name. My Scanner object will be in a separate class called DirectoryServer.java.

I created this pseudo code:
1) for each string in the array list, look at the 4th word
2) if the user search = 4th word, the directory contains the person (ignore case)
3) return all strings that contain the last name

I tried writing the code but I'm just confused on how I can look at the fourth word of each string, how I can return the entire string if it contains the last name, and how to ignore case.

```
  public boolean find(String LastName) {
  boolean inDir = false;
  for (int i = 0; i < dir.size; i++) {
     String info= dir[i];
     String[] splitInfo = info.split(" ");
     if splitInfo.contains(LastName) {
        inDir = true;
     }
     return inDir
  } 
}
```

Comment: That code is missing a (very important) brace.

Comment: To ignore case convert to lower (or upper) case and compare against a similarly-cased `lastName`. To return the entire string return the entire string, e.g., `info` in your case.

Comment: the added source code wont compile.. please add code that does compile.

Answer (score 1):

Just split the string using `String[] words = info.split(" ")` (or you may want to use regex for whitespace).

then do `words.length>4 && searchName.equalsIgnoreCase(words[3])`

if it matches then return `info`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's simplify your question. You already know how to iterate on an `ArrayList`.

let's suppose we're iterating on the string `str`. All what you need to do is check if the fourth work is `searchName`, if so, you want to return the whole String:

- `info.split("\\s+")` will split the string according to 1 or more spaces
- check if there exists a fourth element (*very important*) and compare it to whatever you want using [`String#equalsIgnoreCase`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase-java.lang.String-)
- if so, return the `info` string or `str` (I didn't exactly understand what you want to return)

Note that `\s` is a regex that matches a single space, `\s+` matches one or more spaces, and in Java, `\` should be escaped, the result will be `\\`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean find(String LastName) {
  boolean inDir = false;
  for (int i = 0; i < dir.size; i++) {
     String info = dir[i];
     //Splits the string by space.
     String[] splitInfo = info.split(" ");
     //Checking if the string array has 4 elements in it.
     if(splitInfo.size() >= 4){
         //Taking fourth element and checking with lastname(case ignored)
         if splitInfo[3].equalsIgnoreCase(LastName) {
            //If equals returning the whole string.
            return info;
         }
     // Else returning false
     return inDir
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can look at split() method from String API.
Split each string from your list based on character space " " and get the 4th element of the result.
Something like :

```
String myString = "Staff 77778 Julie Chang Registrar";
String[] parts = myString.split(" ");
String lastName = parts[3]; // Chang
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:  A quick explanation.

- Iterate over the list using a for each loop.
- Split the current element on a space character, store in an array.
- Retrieve the 4th element from the array, i.e. the last name.
- If the 4th element matches the "LastName" you are searching for, return true.

```
public boolean find(String LastName, List<String> toSearch) {
    boolean inDir = false;
    for (String element : toSearch) {
        String[] splitInfo = info.split(" ");
        String thisLastName = splitInfo[3];
        if (LastName.equalsIgnoreCase(thisLastName) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return inDir
}
```

Comment: Explaining what your code does would be better. Also, not checking to make sure you got 4 elements in the array is not wise.

Comment: Sure, you're open to a null pointer exception.  If you require validation throw it in there - if you get that null pointer exception at any point then the requirements were wrong ;)

Comment: You've got the wrong error, it wouldn't be the equality that would not work, it's getting the fourth element : `splitInfo[3]` and we have no idea what the requirements are.

Comment: Apologies, array index out of bounds exception, been a while since I've seen one of them.  Using a space separated list wouldnt be my go to method of storing data.  As far as I'm concered "the fourth element is the last name", why should I not believe that?  Are you telling me the data wasn't validated on input?  Madness I say!

Comment: Agree with ConMan.  If the format MUST be 4 strings per line, then there is no reason to validate that there are 4 elements in the array.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code has a little bit of flaws, try this:

```
public boolean find(String lastName) {
  boolean inDir = false;
  lastName = lastNamer.toLowerCase();
  for (int i = 0; i < dir.size(); i++) {     //Assuming dir is your arrayList
   String info = dir.get(i);
   String info = info.toLowerCase();
   String[] splitInfo = info.split(" ");

   if(splitInfo[3].equals(lastName))    //spliInfo[3] will always contain a last name
      inDir = true;
  return inDir
  } 
}
```